# Awk script to match a pattern and then remove entire line after delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file which has several lines with alphanumeric strings like ZINC123345667_123 followed by other lines. Now, I need to remove the digits after the delimiter "_" in only lines with strings containing "ZINC" and rest of the other lines remaining the same. I have tried using the below awk command, but obtained only the lines with "ZINC" and not with other lines.

My original Data:

```
 Name:      ZINC00000036_1
 Grid Score:          -23.170839
 Grid_vdw:          -22.304409
 Grid_es:           -0.866430
 Int_energy:            4.932559

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
ZINC00000036_1
 18 18 1 0 0

Name:       ZINC00000053_3
 Grid Score:          -23.739523
 Grid_vdw:          -22.876204
 Grid_es:           -0.863320
 Int_energy:            9.981080

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
ZINC00000053_3
 20 20 1 0 0

 Name:      ZINC00000351_12
 Grid Score:          -30.763229
 Grid_vdw:          -27.735493
 Grid_es:           -3.027738
 Int_energy:            4.097543

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
ZINC00000351_12
 31 31 1 0 0
```

I have executed the below awk script

```
awk -F'_' '/ZINC/ {print $1}' data.file > out.file
```

Output obtained:

```
Name:       ZINC00000036
ZINC00000036
Name:       ZINC00000053
ZINC00000053
Name:       ZINC00000351
ZINC00000351
```

But, I need the other lines too in the output file as below:

```
 Name:      ZINC00000036
 Grid Score:          -23.170839
 Grid_vdw:          -22.304409
 Grid_es:           -0.866430
 Int_energy:            4.932559

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE ZINC00000036  18 18 1 0 0

 Name:      ZINC00000053
 Grid Score:          -23.739523
 Grid_vdw:          -22.876204
 Grid_es:           -0.863320
 Int_energy:            9.981080

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE ZINC00000053  20 20 1 0 0

 Name:      ZINC00000351
 Grid Score:          -30.763229
 Grid_vdw:          -27.735493
 Grid_es:           -3.027738
 Int_energy:            4.097543

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE ZINC00000351  31 31 1 0 0
```

As my data file is huge and transforming it would be impossible, I will greatly appreciate any help with awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep only the part before the first underscore character `_` on lines containing `ZINC`, and leave the other lines in tact, you can do:

```
awk -F'_' '/ZINC/{print $1;next}1' file
```

Comment: Thank you all for this help. All the scripts worked for my query.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/ZINC/s/_.*//' file
awk '/ZINC/{sub(/_.*/,"")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this with `sed`:

```
sed -E '/ZINC[0-9]+_/s/_.*//' yourfile
```

That says... on any lines that contains "ZINC" followed by some digits then an underscore, substitute (i.e. replace) the underscore and anything else on the line with nothing in `yourfile`.

If you add `-i` after the `sed` command, it allows in-place editing without your needing to create a second file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that awk is the right tool for this job. A simple sed command will do it:

```
sed 's/\(ZINC[0-9]\{1,\}\)_[0-9]\{1,\}/\1/' file  # most portable
sed 's/\(ZINC[0-9]\+\)_[0-9]\+/\1/' file          # GNU sed
sed -E 's/(ZINC[0-9]+)_[0-9]+/\1/' file           # extended regex mode
```

Capture the part before the underscore (ZINC, followed by some digits) and discard the rest.

Same thing in Perl, which is marginally shorter due to the digit character class `\d`:

```
perl -pe 's/(ZINC\d+)_\d+/$1/' file
```

Come to think of it, if you're determined to use awk, this would work:

```
awk -F_ '/ZINC/{$0=$1}1' file
```

When `ZINC` is matched, overwrite the line with the contents of the first field. The `1` at the end ensures that every line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Another format of answer using sed,

```
sed 's/\(ZINC[0-9]*\)\(_.*\)/\1/g' inputfile
```

Replacing the entire string with the first half of the pattern. Rest all other lines will be displayed